# Does not display track record in Google Analytics

Tags: wordpress, pdf, google-analytics, download

I have installed plugin WP Post to PDF to convert a current post in pdf. but now i dont know how many person use this feature on my site. so i want to track of pdf download from my site http://careertest.guru99.com/

Thats why i have added onclick event on this link as below

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Download','Click',this.href])";
```

and also added below code in plugin

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'XX-YYYYYYY-Z', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

So when a user click on Download PDF, a PDF will be downloaded but in Google Analytics it does not display any effect. Means in google analytics it does not display how many people Downloaded PDF and from which post.

Please help me how can i know this.

Thank you

Comment: Check your javascript console. You've got lots of errors, several of these which could be preventing your `onclick` action from executing.

Comment: Hi @cpilko, i have checked in console for error but it displays error in tracking code of google analytics. but it is copy and pasted from my tracking code which is available in my id. i have do only changes in that for Tracking ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the JS syntax errors, if you are using Universal Analytics, then you will need to use the "ga" object (currently you are using the older _gaq object). To send the event through the onclick handler, your Google Analytics code should look something like this

```
ga('send', 'event', 'download', 'PDF', $(this).href);
```

Also note that your quotes should be consistent. Use the single, straight quotes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @nyuen.

Yes you are right i am using older ga object. i have updated obect in my script which is given by you. but still it does not reflect in google analytics. :(

I think problem is in below code

ga('create', 'XX-YYYYYYY-Z', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

instead of "pageview" can we write "event" ? i think it displays track record of page view not an event. so for this i have to write here "event" or "events" ?

One more question is in google analytics effects displays after 24 hour ? because i am newbie in google analytics so i don't know about it.